# I get Failed to load error in Electron application

Tags: html, css, electron

I am trying to link a font to my Electron app but I get this error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have added this to my CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
```

I have even tried adding this to my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
```

I have also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is some sort of network issue... I'm not going to ask you whether you have an internet connection so is your app loaded via `https`?

Comment: I definitely have internet connection :D
But I don't know if my app loads with http or https (How canI check?) however, I have tried both and also without any protocil

Comment: you can copy paste the url somewhere and it'll show that part... Are you behind any sort of corporate proxy..?

Comment: When I download the font and add it as a css file it works but the performance is so bad.. . It could be some kind of corporate proxy!! I will ask. Thanks! But the URL opens in my browser.

Comment: Yea I've faced issues where the url directly loads in browser but won't work from apps, for example, at work if I try loading jquery cdn from google in stackoverflow code snippet it'll fails, but the file will load if I directly open it in a tab -.- Maybe your app is running on a port which they are monitoring or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample electron boilerplate app includes a line like this in the main electron startup code:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('host-rules', 'MAP * 127.0.0.1');
```

If your code includes that, then all network requests are going to be re-routed back to localhost, which will be a problem.

If that line of code is in your electron startup code, try commenting it out...

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ":" try the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
```

Comment: it was a typo in my question but it my app it is correct